# How to turn off php deprecated alerts in Laravel Valet?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I did a composer update from project and now I get this annoying error below every time I try to run the tinker. I'm using Laravel Valet to serve my projects and tried to put in all php.ini files the error_reporting *error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED* and restarted valet but without success. Anyone knows how to disable this errors correctly?

[image]

```
PHP Deprecated:  The "Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector::pluralize" method is deprecated and will be dropped in doctrine/inflector 2.0. Please update to the new Inflector API. in /Volumes/Joker/multilaser-projetos/multiplik-pro/vendor/doctrine/inflector/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php on line 261
```

Comment: I think you need to exclude `E_USER_DEPRECATED` because those are deprecated warnings coming from doctrine not from PHP